# Sumif for a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2500 rows, each of which looks like this: "amount" "startdate" "enddate"

My output is supposed to look like this: "querydate" "sum"

I want to write a formula that returns the sum of all amounts where the querydate is between the startdate and enddate.

I've tried the following formula: =SUMIFS(amount,querydate,">="&startdate,querydate"<="&enddate). However, it's outputs change every time either startdate or enddate column are sorted, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]. This isn't your standard forum, and it's certainly not a "write my code for me" service. Take a minute take the [tour] and read the [help] to get familiar with the place. Once you've done that, come back [edit] your post to include your best shot at the code to do this and someone will be happy to help you fix issues with it. You're highly unlikely to find someone willing to do your work for you, though.

Comment: Without seeing how you defined these ranges, it is impossible to decipher specifically what you did wrong, but assuming the amount is in Column C, the start date is in Column A, and the end date is in column B, and they all run from  row 1 to row 2500, with the Query Date in E1 the formula should be more like =SUMIFS(C1:C2500,A1:A2500,"<="&E1,B1:B2500,">="&E1)

Comment: Thank you. I was attempting to make sure the query date fits both startdate and enddate simultaneously, and couldn't get past the syntax errors.

Your approach/formula first checks startdate against querydate, and then checks enddate against querydate, yielding results I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to sum the values between two dates?

```
=sumifs(TYPE SUM RANGE HERE;">=01-01-2015";"<01-02-2015")
```

The dates are just an example